# Issues after Project reuse in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, reusability

I am starting reusing code in Flutter. The latest time that I reused a Project in Flutter this is what I did:

1.- Copy the project'd directory with the new desired name

2.- Apply Dart package named "change app package name" version 1.0.0 https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

3.- Search in the scope of the project for all the instances where the old project's name still kept in the new project

4.- Keep in mind that the old name, still will be present in the ~/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com//<suffix_of_your_package>

5.- Keep in mind that for Android it's necessary to change applicationId in the  app/build.gradle file

6.- Same for iOS bundle identifier in Xcode.

Today I have started a new Futter project from scratch and I have copied all the relevant files to the new project

These files are:

- lib directory
- asset directory with fonts, translations, localized texts and logo  file
- all modular files for the main.dart file
- images directory

I have adapted app/build.graddle and iOS bundle identifier.

after that I get lots of new initilization errors that, simply, don't exist in the original project. Original project run on physical devices for Android and iOS

Errors are of this kind...
Could you give a hand with this?

```
Error: Field 'flutterTts' should be initialized because its type 'FlutterTts' doesn't allow null.
```

Comment: If you have separate layers you can always host in your own repo and use that. Like if you have a network/data layer you can easily add them like how you 3rd party packages.

Comment: Sorry, @GoodSp33d I'm unable to understand your comment. Could you expand it a little bit?

Comment: My bad, I meant to create your own packages/modules. So you don't have to copy/paste

Comment: Yes you point to another important point: I use github and I have separate modules in the proyect. This makes the error hunt more interesting. On the other hand it's a good way for organizing the code. :) and for keeping track of changes and so on. ;)

Answer (score 3):

this is my opinion, if you want to reuse project in Flutter,

1. create the project with the bundle name from the beginning, so you don't need to change the bundle name manually, with

> flutter create --org com.yourdomain appname

2. copy and replace lib folder from old project to the new project
3. compare pubspec.yaml file, just merge all the plugin you use on the old project to the new project
4. for Android, you can compare these files/folders inside the android folder on your flutter project. (Note: you might have another file/folder to compare, depend on your configuration from the old project, but these files/folders listed is the one usually have changes)

- build.gradle
- gradle.properties
- app/build.gradle
- app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
- res/
- kotlin/

5. for iOS, you can compare only compare ios/Runner/Info.plist. For me this is the only file that I ever change, if you have other files inside this ios folder that you need to compare or implement some changes, you can do it.

If you use some plugin like flutter_launcher_icons, you might need to run some command first to change the app icon after you finish all those step.

Comment: I have started by creating a new project from scratch, and now I'm fighting errors that didn't appear in the original project. I will need to initialize Strings, Keys, List<> and other stuff that didn't need to be initialized in the original project. Looks a good way and we have to keep in mind that this kind of errors will be appearing.